# Draw line with faded ends

Tags: android, graphics, drawing

Is it possible in Android to programmatically draw a line using a path, such that the middle section is a solid color but both ends fade from that color to transparent?  The path will be a series of calculated coordinates.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, use a generic View widget with a drawable that contains a gradient as its background.

Make sure it extends to match_parent in the direction you want it to cut your layout and it's 1px tall or wide in the other dimension.

The gradient should be a simple linear gradient transparent to solid to transparent.

[Here](http://envyandroid.com/archives/242/drawable-gradient-lines-android) is a very nice tutorial.

**Update:**
The above link is dead, try [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/288414/Create-Gradient-Lines-with-Drawables-in-Android) one instead.

Comment: @AkshayTaru I updated my answer with a working link... ;)